# inspect changes after a git pull merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-diff

is it possible to play a git diff in the changes brought by the automatic merge after a `git pull`?

Usually, if there are any conflicts i can check on those using normal git diff, but no idea how to do it when the pull was successful (and the changes were automatically commited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've just done the `git pull` you can look the difference between the current `HEAD` and the previous one with something like:

```
git diff HEAD@{1}
```